# In Yammer Embed commenting, can I stop it from automatically attaching the current page URL?

Tags: sharepoint-online, yammer, spfx

I want to use [Yammer Embed](https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/commenting) to provide comments for SharePoint Online pages. If I do this, every time I start a new thread, it automatically attaches the current URL to the comment.

[image: Screenshot of Yammer Embed comment box]

This then looks pretty ugly in the list of displayed comments.

[image: Screenshot of Yammer Embed comment showing URL preview]

I don't understand why this is useful, since users already know what page they are on. It is possible to click the X when writing your post, to remove the URL attachment. But can I disable it by default, so users never need to do that?

Here's my embed code:

```
  public render(): void {
this.domElement.innerHTML = `
  <div class="${styles.commentBox}">
    <div class="${styles.embed}">
    </div>
  </div>
`;
(window as any).yam.connect.embedFeed({
  container: "." + styles.embed,
  network: "contoso.com",
  feedType: "open-graph",
  config: {
    header: false,
    footer: false,
    showOpenGraphPreview: false,
    promptText: "Comment on this page"
  }
});
```

}